# Can't enlarge swap partition on LVM - 256 extents needed, but only 0 available

Tags: partitioning, swap, lvm, ubuntu-mate

some days ago I installed the latest release candidate of Ubuntu (mate) 17.04 on my PC and configured it for LVM usage.

I just have 4Gb of RAM and I found out that the swap space created on my SSD during the S.O. installation was not that big (just 700Mb or so). Since I often work with multiple browsers, android studio and other tools open at the same time I think I'd be happier with a larger swap space.

I tried to make it larger so by performing the following

```
  sudo lvs

  LV     VG             Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   ubuntu-mate-vg -wi-ao---- 231,41g                                                    
  swap_1 ubuntu-mate-vg -wi-ao---- 996,00m
```

then

```
  sudo swapoff /dev/ubuntu-mate-vg/swap_1
```

followed by

```
  sudo lvresize -L+1G /dev/ubuntu-mate-vg/swap_1
```

which returned

```
    Insufficient free space: 256 extents needed, but only 0 available
```

That was unexpected. I think I need to shrink my data partition of 1Gb in order to make the swap bigger? How can I do so? Can I resize the partition I'm using?

Thank you for your help

Marco